# Oracle - How to enforce Start_Date < End_Date Constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle 11g, I want to create a table with two date columns and ensure that one of them is always less than the other.  The columns would be:

```
START_DATE   DATE NOT NULL
END_DATE     DATE NOT NULL
```

And the rule is that `START_DATE < END_DATE`.

Should I do this in a constraint on each column?
Or in an `AFTER ROW` trigger on the table?

Comment: The answer (which Gordon has given already) is "no" and "no". You can't enforce this with a constraint on "EACH" column, and you don't need a trigger on this. You need a row-level constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You just add a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_dates check (start_date < end_date)
```

Note that you don't even have to check for `NULL` in the constraint (the boolean logic will return `NULL` if either value is `NULL`.  Constraint logic -- as opposed to `WHERE` and `WHEN` -- only treats explicit "false" as not passing, so `NULL` satisfies the constraint.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the last comment. If a business requirement is that the dates be NOT NULL, then the < constraint alone will NOT guarantee non-nullness, precisely for the reason you gave. So if NOT NULL is required, it MUST be given explicitly on each column and not left to the < check constraint.